# search a string in dynamic log file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a windows batch script for the following.

I have some log files under path `C:\test\` which are being created everyday having date of that day in their names. i.e.

```
u_ex130828.log     (created on 28/08/2013)
u_ex130827.log     (created on 28/08/2013)
u_ex130826.log     (created on 28/08/2013)
```

I want to search a specific error message in all the files created today only.
And as soon as error message found then immediately append the complete line having error message into a text file named Output.txt and If error message doesn't found then don't append the Output.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set "today=%YY%%MM%%DD%"

findstr /i /c:"File attached above for last 2 occasions." "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*%today%.log" > "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\output.txt"
```

Comment: Great..!..Its working..Thanks a ton..!!
What changes i need to make above if i want to search another string with this string using OR.

Comment: If you want to search for another string then add a second `/c:"string to find"` after the one that is already there.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\
set "today=%date:~-4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%"
for %%a in (*%today%.log) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /c:"File attached above for last 2 occasions." "%%~a"') do (
        (echo %%~a: %%~b)>>Output.txt
    )
)
```

Modify the file search pattern `*%today%.log` for your needs.

Comment: I am going to throw a cautionary note here.  Small files, this is fine.  If you try to search large files (500MB+), you can possibly slow a server down.  There are tools like Grep, Hjsplit and other methods.